# Power BI Indirect Relationship Filter Issue

Tags: powerbi

I have 3 tables:
Employee
Survey
Manager

Employee tbl has direct relationship with both tables, however there is no direct relationship between survey and manager.

I am trying to create a chart/scorecard which does the average score on a question in surgery tbl. This works fine, however I would like to filter this by managers name from manager tbl, and this does not work.

Any help please?

Comment: Just follow the filter direction on the model (1 --> Many Side). If Survey is the many side, then It can't reach the Manager because It needs to follow the path (Survey --> Employee -- > Manager). In that case, Employee will be one side, and Filter context will stay there! No filtering will occur. To overcome the problem, In that case, You need to make the filter direction both.

Answer (score 1):

If you configure a 1-many relationship from Manager to Employee, and a 1-many relationship from Employee to Survey then filters will flow from Manager to Employee to Survey.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting an error when I try to do this. It says the cardinality you selected isn't valid for this relationship